# How to extract OS name and major version using regex?

Tags: regex, centos, redhat

I am trying to find the regex to extract the first two words and the first number from the /etc/redhat-release

ie

```
CentOS Linux release 7.9.28 (Core) = CentOS Linux 7
CentOS Stream release 8 = CentOS Stream 8
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo) = Red Hat 7
```

If possible could you explain how the capture is working? I’ve tried various regexs and can’t seem to grasp the capture.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/WU9bNi/1  words and number are in two separate groups

Comment: The first part seems obvious now, but I’m still not understanding [^0-9]*(\d).*

Comment: Did you read the right pane? It explains everything in every detail.

Comment: There is no right pane on mobile when I clicked the link. So I assumed it was just a regex sandbox. I reopened it on my laptop and I can see the right pane description now.